# Python Is_Prime method problem. i need a for loop with that and so it can print it without print being in the function

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

Instructions:
Make a method named is_prime that receives a number as a parameter.  The method should return True if the number is prime, or False if the number is not prime.  The method should not do any printing.
Test the method by using a for loop to test a series of at least 10 numbers.  You don't have to increment the loop by 1 each time.

Background:
A number is prime if it is only evenly divisible by 1 and itself.  For example, 7 and 11 are prime.  6, 21, 100 are NOT prime.

Algorithm for Finding a Prime Number:
The best approach is to test to see if the number is NOT PRIME.  If that test fails, then the number is prime.
for divisors from 2 through the int(square root of our number) + 1
    if number divided by the divisor has no remainder
        then the number is not prime

if the for loop ends and the number has not been declared "not prime"
    then the number is prime

To find the square root of a number:
import math     # put at the top of the file
math.sqrt(num)  # returns the square root of num

Sample Output:
2 is prime
3 is prime
4 is not prime
5 is prime
6 is not prime
7 is prime
8 is not prime
9 is not prime
10 is not prime
11 is prime
12 is not prime

This is the code:

```
import math

def is_prime(num):
  #max_divisor = int(math.sqrt(num))
  if num < 2:
    return False

  else:
    for x in range (2, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
      if num % x == 0:
        return False
  return True

def execute():
  if is_prime == True:
    print( is_prime , "is prime")
  else:
    print( is_prime,"is not prime")

is_prime(3) 
execute()
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: `if is_prime == True:` should be `if is_prime(some_number):`

Comment: @ChrisCharley Hello. I did search it up. I checked many other existing codes too but none of them have the for loop that will test 10 different numbers. I dont know how to implement this modification.

Comment: _ I checked many other existing codes too but none of them have the for loop that will test 10 different numbers._ Can you be more specific, what _10 different numbers_ are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

`if is_prime == True:` is not calling the function. It's simply testing whether the variable `is_prime`, which names the function, contains the value `True`.

Use a `for` loop to call the function repeatedly with different numbers.

```
def execute():
    for i in range(1, 20):
        if is_prime(i):
            print(i, "is prime")
        else:
            print(i, "is not prime")
```

Comment: Sorry as i am learning but i still dont understand how do i implement that and how does your code combine with mine if when you are testing the  if is_prime(i): it just asks for a number and doesnt check if the number is returned as True or False?

Comment: Replace your `execute` function with this one.

Comment: `if` tests if the expression is true. You don't need to write `== True`

Comment: Ok. thank you i just solved the problem. i didnt understand what you told me but now i got it working. I didnt understand that you had to to type execute instead of is_prime as i kept thinking of my friends code.

Comment: `if <expression>:` tests if `<expression>` returns a truthy value. Your function returns `True`, which is a truthy value. You don't need to compare `True == True` for that expression to be truthy.